# Can I associate my account with posts I made before registering?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I posted a couple of questions as an unregistered user (this is not a Google account or a standard OpenID account).  Later, I added myself as a registered user through my Gmail account.  Is there a way to club both the e-mail addresses and use one account?

I am able to post comments and ask questions, but am unable to delete anything I post (the existing work as an unregistered user).

Has anyone else faced this problem and is there a workaround?

Comment: You should ask this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You can always send an email to team@stackoverflow.com (the address at the bottom of every page) and explain your situation, or flag any of your posts for moderator attention. You'll have to identify the old user (to be merged with the new one) and provide some sort of proof that both accounts belong to the same person (e.g. by supplying the email adrdress used for each one, and the sending mail from that address).

Comment: I don't think just telling them the email address would be enough. For example, I publish the email I use with StackOverflow.